# Multiple comment plugin loading on Blogger

Tags: google-plus, blogger, comments, intense-debate

on my blog I’m using from a long time the IntenseDebate pluging as commenting system in place of the default one.

I would replace it with Google+ comment system but I don’t want to lose all comments already left by the users via IntenseDebate, so I would figure out if there’s any way to load on the old posts the IntenseDebate pluging in place of the default Google+.

As possible solution, I’m thinking something like a tag in the html post code that (if defined) load the IntenseDebate pluging.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

its not posible to migrate IntenseDebate comment on google plus. Their is one solution that you can use multiple comment system in your blogger blog. just few month ago i had written trick for the same. I hope that this will be useful to you.

http://www.tipsviablogging.com/multiple-comment-system-blogspot/

Comment: Hi Umesh, thank you for your reply! Your solution is really interesting but I would preserve IntesenDebate for the posts with high numbers of comments!